# Java running out of memory when using collect_list in PySpark

Tags: java, database, hadoop, hive, pyspark

I'm currently working with PySpark and running a query on a table that has about 600 million records. The table itself is around 300gb. My query looks something like this:

```
select f1, collect_list(struct(f2, f3)) as fdata
from table
group by 1
```

Currently, I'm getting this error:

```
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 1010"...
Killed
```

Another thing is that the distribution of `(f2, f3)` tuples is not even. Some `f1` has maybe 100k such tuples while some other `f1` may only have 5. I suspect `collect_list` is causing some issues.

I can always increase the cluster size, but I'm wondering if I can do something about the tables instead. Partitioning by `f1` is not an option either since it has very high dimensionality. I don't have too much experience with Spark or Hive so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are apparently trying to load all rows of a huge resultset into memory.

> I suspect collect_list is causing some issues.

That is most likely right.

The solution is either going to be to increase the heap size<sup>1</sup> or change the way that you process the resultset so that you *don't* need to hold it all in memory at the same time.

---

<sup>1 - ... and possibly by more RAM, a bigger machine, etc.  You can see where this is going.</sup>

Comment: Do you mean I'm trying to load the huge result set from `collect_list` into memory or you mean the table I'm reading is being loaded into memory?

Comment: The former.  At least, that's what it looks like to me.

Comment: Increasing heap size worked, but I will need to look into processing the data differently. Seems like I’m just masking the problem right now.